# can i mount 'public on xxx' to local fs?

Tags: linux, networking

I am using Fedora and I can see the public folders from other computers on my network as 'public on xxx'. Is there any way to mount that to the local fs? The way it is now I can only access it in the file manager.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a newer version of Fedora:

```
mount -t cifs //xxx/public -o username=john,password=smith /mountpoint
```

Older versions of mount will specify `smbfs` instead of `cifs`. If the share is not password protected, you can use `guest` in the mount options.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the share through file manager, it *is* reachable through the file system. GNOME's `gvfs` mounts can be accessed through `~/.gvfs/`.